# Delete "jacknode" in NSString - iOS

Tags: ios, regex, parsing, text, nsstring

I have an iOS app which downloads and parses a JSON file. The JSON file returns the following data which I am storing in a NSString:

```
{
    jacknode = "The Lite - Mon, Sep, 14, 2015 - 12:00 GMT";
}
```

Is there a way of using Regex to delete the curly brackets and preferebly the "jacknode =" part of the string?

I tried creating a NSString and even resorted to using the `[string description]` method to see if the brackets would get deleted but they didn't. This tells me that the curly brackets are actually **PART OF THE STRING**. I don't mind that, but how can I manually delete them.

Note: If you are wandering why the JSON file returns such weirdly formatted data... well its a long story and I don't have time to change it right now.

Thanks for your time, Dan.

Comment: if you got valid json response then just get the value by key name

Comment: How are you getting the value into the string in the first place?

Comment: @EICaptain But the value by key name actually returns the above data. As I stated in my answer, those curly brackets are part of the string!

Comment: @trojanfoe ```NSString *test = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", data[0]];```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to parse the JSON content using `[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:options:error:]`.  Assuming `data` contains the server response, then:

```
NSError *error = nil;
NSDictionary *dict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data
                                                     options:0
                                                       error:&error];
if (dict) {
    NSString *string = dict[@"jacknode"];
} else {
    // Error
}
```

Comment: Ahhh.... I was the idiot all along... I just tried this and it worked perfectly. Hmmm I need to go over another JSON parsing tutorial/guide it seems. Thanks anyway!